# solidity smart contract encode function for safety reason

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have one simple question.

So when we deal with smart contract on chain,
why don't we make encode function just in case for safety?

for example,

```
    function encodeFunction(address _callee, bytes calldata _callData, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = callee.call{vaule: _value}(_callData);
        require(success, "tx failed");
        return success;
    }
```

Suppose that we are able to figure out any contract address and calldata, Isn't it much safer to have this kind of function to deal with any situation?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't someone just listen to the encodeFunction and its parameters? For example etherscan allows users to see function calls and parameters .That would defeat the whole purpose of your encode function.

Also having this kind of function defeats the whole purpose of transparency of the concept blockchain.

Comment: okay let me clarify my opinion. What I meant for safety was to deal with any kind of emergency situation. For example, if the smart contract got an airdrop of certain token and has no function to withdraw, it can be a problem. I think encode function can deal with these kind of situation. I think this is nothing to do with transparency since every one can find out what the contract is calling by etherscan like you said.